# Spring MVC - Run function inside controller continuously until user terminates it also show the status of execution on UI

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, I have to run a function continuously in a controller until user terminates it also I have to maintain progress on UI simultaneously. I did the first part i.e. continuously run function using ExecutorService but I am not getting how to sync it with UI to show progress.

Currently what happening is as soon as I run that controller the view is returned and ExecutorService keeps running in background, I have to return the view only if the user terminates the operation.

Comment: To clarify, you want to return the view when the ExecutorService terminates and the Future isDone()?

Comment: @NathanRussell  Yes, exactly.

Comment: can you describe your application and scenario some more please? As you've currently written it, it sounds like you want the user to submit a HTTP request to a controller. The controller will not return at that point, but instead will start a process via ExecutorService. And then at some point in the future, the same user will make some other request to terminate the original request? Is that it? If so, it sounds a bit weird to me ... If the 1st request doesn't return, how does the user submit the 2nd request to terminate the 1st?

Comment: yes, right, that's what I want to do, so instead making other request to terminate the ExecutorService,can we use contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) method of ServletContextListner to terminate the ExecutorService?